# Is there a way to simplify this function using a one-line comprehension in python?

Tags: python

simple question, as the title implies. I was hoping to use the zip function but can't get it to work for some reason.

```
def tuple_sum(A, B):
out = []
for a,b in [x for x in zip(A,B)]:
    out1 = []
    for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
        out1.append(a1+b1)
    out.append(out1)
return out
```

Comment: Please give an example input/output, and also fix your indentation.

Comment: Do you have a nested structure? Also `for a,b in [x for x in zip(A,B)]:` should be simplified to `for a,b in zip(A,B):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```py
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
B = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
s = [[a1 + b1 for a1, b1 in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(A, B)]
print(s)  # [[6, 8], [10, 12]]
```